# subsitute removing zero numbering

Tags: command-substitution

I would like to subsitute in a txt file the followings targets for example

"code_000040" by "code_40" and "code_067340" by "code_67340" and so on..,

in other words to remove the zeros in the 6 number ids before the real numbering id starts

Plaese any help!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use sed:

```
for file in code_*; do
  newname=$(echo $file | sed 's/_0*/_/')
  mv "$file" "$newname" #you may want to use -i to avoid accidents
done
```

I usually write this out in one line.

The outer loop can be anything: a for loop with a glob as above, a list of files, or even a find command piped into while read;

Comment: do you mean something like the following in linux in one line?

for filename in code_*; do newname=$(echo $filename | sed 's/_0*/_/')

Comment: @user61677 exactly, just continue the line, adding semicolons between commands (in separate lines semicolons are optional, but in one line you need them). Or you can even do something like
for filename in code_*; do mv "$filename" "$(echo $filename | sed 's/_0*/_/')"; done

That the quotes are there for safety in case you have spaces or some other strange characters in the filenames.

Comment: This changes the file's name, not its contents. @user61677 is that what you want or do you want to replace text _inside_ the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the text within the file, with GNU `sed`, you could do:

```
sed -i 's/code_0*\([0-9]\)/code_\1/g' file.txt
```

or

```
perl -i -pe 's/code_0+(\d+)/code_$1/g' file.txt
```

That will modify the original file, remove the `-i` to keep the file unchanged or give an argument to `-i` to create a backup file (this will create a copy of the original called `file.txt.bak`):

```
perl -i.bak  -pe 's/code_0+(\d+)/code_$1/g' file.txt
```

Comment: That would turn `code_000000 code_000001` to `code_ code_1` though.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas true. Not sure how the OP would want to deal with `code_00000`, I am assuming that won't exist (cheating, I know) and that numbers begin from `1`.

Comment: Just make it `sed -i 's/code_0*\([0-9]\)/code_\1/g'`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas fair enough. Done, thanks again.

Comment: And a '/.*/w file.bak;s/...' never hurts, at least to test before diving right in to inline replacement...